# ef core 5.0 : sqlite error after migration : error near "max"

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I updated my solution and all sub projects to net core 5.0, including ef core.
I'm now facing an issue while running my unit tests when they use sqlite to make a temporary db file (with a unique name). keeping in mind that it all worked fine with netcore 3.1, both on local and on VSTS.

The issue is raised when I apply Migrate on the new db:

```
 var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=test-" + guid + ".db", b => b.MigrationsAssembly("xxx.Repository"));
        using (var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
        {
            dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

the error states that

```
`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException
SQLite Error 1: 'near "max": syntax error'.
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)

I don't know on what field, line or file it's failing though.
The db is built code-first, and has a dozen of migrations already. the only 'max' I could find are in the migration .Designer.cs like

```
b.Property<string>("MyField").HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
```

and the ApplicationDbContextSnapshot.cs (with the exact same lines on every nvarchar fields).

For a bit of context, this app runs on a MsSql server, and TUs use boh InMemory and SqlLite (when relational is needed).

I updated every Microsofft packages, including Sqlite, to 5.0.
Does anyone faced this already or have a solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `max` recognized by SQLite?  You may need to define the datatype differently for different db providers.  I think the equivalent for sqlite would be "text" datatype.

Comment: You can't switch providers with migrations, they are provider specific

Comment: Yeah, that's invalid syntax for Sqlite. When using `type(width)`, the width has to be numeric (And promptly gets ignored). One of the few cases where it actually cares about the type.

Answer (score 1):

As @Shawn said, one solution is to replace nvarchar(max) by nvachar([int]).

@ErikEJ : we've been switching providers since the beginning of the project years ago to unit test it. So far we had no breaking change like this between two providers given our use cases are fairly simple. The most troublesome issue we had with sqlite is it's inability to drop/alter a column, which can be circunvent with a create/flush/drop script.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: haha, I thought you literally meant `nvachar([int])`, but with `[int]` you mean "an integer number"